# Compass Sprites Error: undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass`

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

I am trying to generate sprites with Compass/SASS and am getting the following error:

`NoMethodError on line ["21"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.1/lib/chunky_png/chunk.rb: undefined method 'unpack' for nil:NilClass`

My icons are all in `images/icons`. And this is my `_sprites.scss` partial:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

My Compass `config.rb`:

```
http_path = "../../www"
css_dir = "../../www/css"
sass_dir = "../../www/sass"
images_dir = "../../www/images"
javascripts_dir = "../../www/js"
output_style = :compressed
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am on a Mac if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by Compass not being able to read an image file.

I ran all my icons through [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) and the sprite generation works fine now. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800892/76363) suggested using optipng (which is bundled in ImageOptim) - that might be a better solution on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I halted a compass compile operation (CNTRL + C) and afterward when trying to run it again this was happening. Was able to solve it by deleting the generated sprite file and running "compass clean" and running "compass compile" command afterward. I guess the sprite image was corrupted due to interrupting the process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my case it was loss of one image by sprite. After added it back, everything works fine. It's funny becouse usually Sass always said about it, but in this case Sass decide said about it like "undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass".

Hope it's help someone.